# What is the British term for the place where people change clothes at the gym?

Tags: word-request, british-english

What is the common British term for the place where people change the clothes at the gym?

In my dictionary I found that there are three results for my language word: wardrobe, cloakroom, checkroom. and I'm not sure what one of them is appropriate for BrE.

I checked the term "cloakroom" on [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cloakroom) and I'm not sure that this is the word that I'm looking for since its definition is:

> "a room in a public building such as a restaurant, theatre, etc. where coats, bags, and other personal things can be left while their owners are in the building"

While I'm talking about the place where people change their clothes, such as in the gym, swimming pool, beach, sports hall etc.

[image]

Comment: Three times in this question you've used ***change*** in the idiomatic sense of stripping off one's current clothing and putting on something different. So I'm surprised you're not aware of the collocation [***changing room***](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/changing-room) (often ***locker room*** in AmE, as per Trump's "locker room talk", but they're always "sports-related", whereas a BrE "changing room" might be provided in a clothing store for customers to try things on for size, etc.).

Comment: The way that Native English speaker thinks is different than the way that non native English speaker thinks. Believe me:). I would never think that the name of that place would be "changing room". I'm lucky because I asked my question here, I almost decided to use the word "cloakroom" because I found some correct pictures on google with this word, But I still felt that it's not clear after I saw the definition on Cambridge dictionary. Anyway - thank you for the comment:) It really helped me.

Comment: Note that here in Canada we would always say "changeroom", not "changing room".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the comment (of FumbleFingers) here, I discovered on Wikipedia detailing about the **changing room**:

> "Various types of *changing rooms* exist:
>
> **Changing stalls** are small stalls where clothes can be changed in privacy. They are used for swimming purposes.
>
> **Locker rooms** are usually gender-specific spaces where clothes are changed and stored in lockers. They are often used for swimming or
>   other sporting purposes. They are open spaces with no stalls.
>
> **Fitting rooms, or dressing rooms**, are usually small single-user cubicles where a person may try on clothes. These are often found at
>   retail stores where one would want to try on clothes before purchasing
>   them.
>
> **Green rooms and trap rooms** are usually mixed-gender backstage or under-stage changing spaces found at theaters and other similar
>   venues.

Comment: Most green rooms are places you wait to go on stage - you generally don't change in them. "Locker room" sounds (to me) a bit more American than changing room.

Comment: @Francis, I agree with you on "green room" and I would add that the place where a *performer* changes their clothes is called a "dressing room" in American usage. In most venues there is one large dressing room for female performers to share, another large dressing room for male performers to share, and sometimes one or two "star" dressing rooms which would accommodate a single person each.

Comment: @randomhead - of course "dressing room" is exactly right for where a performer would change. When I used to do chorus line type things we would change clothes and prepare in the dressing room but might wait in a green room (if we had one).

Answer (score 12):

It is called a [changing room](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/changing-room).

> A room where people can change their clothes, for example before and
>   after sports or, in a shop, where people can try on clothes before
>   buying them